# Sorting from Tuple - Index out of Range

Tags: python, sorting, indexing

```
def mkEntry(file1):
    for line in file1:
        lst = (line.rstrip().split(","))
        print("Old", lst)
        print(type(lst))
        lst = tuple(lst)
        print(type(lst)) #still showing type='list'
        print("Old2", lst)
    sorted(lst, key=operator.itemgetter(1,2))


def main():
    openFile = 'yob' + input("Enter the year <Do NOT include 'yob' or .'txt' : ") + '.txt'
    file1 = open(openFile)
    mkEntry(file1)

main()
```

Error I received:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ranbir/Desktop/names/top101.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/ranbir/Desktop/names/top101.py", line 18, in main
    mkEntry(file1)
  File "/Users/ranbir/Desktop/names/top101.py", line 12, in mkEntry
    sorted(lst, key=operator.itemgetter(1,2))
IndexError: string index out of range
```

File:

```
Tom,M,1658
Anthony,M,985
Lisa,F,88976
Ben,M,6989
Shelly,F,8975
```

I need help sorting the order from `F` to `M` then smallest numbers to largest numbers. The output should look like this:

```
Shelly,F,8975
Lisa,F,8976
Ben,M,698
Anthony,M,985
Tom,M,1658
```

So basically, females first then smallest to largest numbers, then male then smallest to largest (`M=male`, `f=female`).

Comment: `lst` is just *one* line; one tuple. Not a list of tuples. You are trying to sort `('Shelly', 'F', '8975')`.

Comment: Oops, It is suppose to be outside the for loop. I updated.

Comment: `Ben,M,6989` in input, `Ben,M,698` in output ?

Comment: Note that even in Objective-C, if you set a variable inside a loop and then call a function with that variable after and outside the loop, you'll only act on the last value of the loop.  Similarly, if you call a function which doesn't act in place and don't do anything with the return value, the code won't do what you expect.

Comment: I forgot to put the 'return' in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are constantly reassigning `lst` in the loop:

```
for line in file1:
    lst = (line.rstrip().split(","))
    lst = tuple(lst)

sorted(lst, key=operator.itemgetter(1,2))
```

You are not building a final list of all entries. You need a *separate* list object for that:

```
results = []
for line in file1:
    lst = line.rstrip().split(",")
    lst = tuple(lst)
    results.append(lst)

return sorted(results, key=operator.itemgetter(1,2))
```

Note that you need to *return* the sorted list too.

This will still not do what you expect, because your last element (at index 2) is still a string. `'10'` will sort *before* `'91234'` because strings are sorted lexagraphically. Make that a number instead:

```
results = []
for line in file1:
    lst = line.rstrip().split(",")
    lst[2] = int(lst[2])
    lst = tuple(lst)
    results.append(lst)

return sorted(results, key=operator.itemgetter(1,2))
```

Comment: In your third code, It is showing the error: `lst[2] = float(lst[2])
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Ooops, I have the enter space in my textfile. It works. Thank you.